# Почему криво работает мой код?

Tags: php, mysql

В общем, у меня есть форма и список. Когда я ввожу новые данные в форму и жму кнопку "Сохранить", данные добавляются в БД, страница обновляется и в списке появляется строка с новыми данными, все нормально.
Но когда жму кнопку "Удалить", данные исчезают из БД, страница перезагружается, но в списке продолжает светиться удаленная строка. И пока я сам не обновлю страницу, эту строку видно. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот мой код (все на одной странице):

```
<? 
    $database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'portfolio');
    function get_articles($database) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM articles";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($database, $sql2);
        $articles = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $articles; // подключил БД
    }

    $articles = get_articles($database); // сделал запрос для массива


    if (isset($_POST["slogan"])) { // если нажал на кнопку "Сохранить"
        if (isset($_GET['red'])) { 
          $sql = mysqli_query($database, "UPDATE `articles` SET `article` = '{$_POST['words']}',`head` = '{$_POST['slogan']}', `link` = '{$_POST['silka']}' WHERE `id`={$_GET['red']}"); // если это редактирование, в форму должны выйти все данные из строки, на которую я нажал (эта часть кода не работает тоже, но сейчас главное решить главную проблему)
        } else {
          $sql = mysqli_query($database, "INSERT INTO `articles` (`article`, `head`, `link`) VALUES ('{$_POST['words']}', '{$_POST['slogan']}', '{$_POST['silka']}')"); // если это создание новой строки, то в БД добавляются введенные данные
          header('location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //редирект
          exit;
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/edit.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Административный вход</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="edit" id="edit">

    <div class="rewievs-top"><h4>Редактирование портфолио</h4></div> 

    <div class="fields">
        <div class="edit-left">

            <? foreach ($articles as $items): ?> //вот тут выводится список со строками из БД
            <div class="art">
                <h3><?=$items['head'];?></h3>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <? echo "<a href='?del={$items['id']}'>Удалить</a>"?> 
                    <? echo "<a href='?red={$items['id']}'>Редактировать</a>"?> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <? endforeach; ?>

        </div>
        <div class="edit-right">
                    <form id="sendwords" method="post"> //моя форма
                        <input tabindex="0" type="text" value="" placeholder="Название статьи" id="slogan" name="slogan" autocomplete="off" class="slogan"> 
                        <textarea tabindex="0" rows="7" value="" cols="50" type="text" id="words" autocomplete="off" name="words" class="words" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Текст статьи"></textarea>
                        <input tabindex="0" type="text" value="" placeholder="Ссылка на источник" id="silka" name="silka" autocomplete="off" class="silka">
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a href="?add=new">Добавить</a>
                            <input tabindex="0" class="sohr" type="submit" id="redact" name="redact" value="Сохранить">
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

//Если я нажимаю кнопку Удалить, выполняется этот код
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($database, "DELETE FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = {$_GET['del']}");

}

// Тут страница должна обновиться, но она не обновляется, если я удалил что-то. Вернее, обновляется, но старые данные с нее не удаляются, пока не обновишь сам
if (isset($_GET['red'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT `id`, `article`, `head`, `link` FROM `articles` WHERE `id`={$_GET['red']}");
    $articles = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
}
```

С редактированием бы тоже разобраться, но пока главное вот это.

Comment: Код на вашей странице выполняется линейно вне зависимости от действия. До удаления нужной вам статьи вы извлекаете все статьи из БД и выдаёте их пользователю. Вам нужно сделать разделение в коде и выполнять только соответствующий действию PHP код и выводить для него нужный HTML.

Comment: то есть код удаления лучше передвинуть выше?

Comment: Да, заработало, спасибо.

Comment: А вот с редактированием так и не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте удаление через редирект. Можно вынести код для удаления данных в отдельный файл, например, delete.php. После удаления выполнить редирект на страницу с нужным вам списком.

Comment: было бы хорошо с кодом

Comment: сделать ссылку на файл, который будет обрабатывать удаление: 
строку <? echo "<a href='?del={$items['id']}'>Удалить</a>"?> заменить, например, на
<? echo "<a href='/delete.php?del={$items['id']}'>Удалить</a>"?>

В файл delete.php  вынести ваш код по удалению записи:
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($database, "DELETE FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = {$_GET['del']}");

}
В случае успешного удаления делаем редирект на страницу со списком с помощью header location как у вас это
сделано для сохранения записи. Если уделение было неуспешным, можно вывести какое-то сообщение.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А с редактированием не в курсе в чем проблема?

Comment: Для редактирования сделайте по аналогии с удалением. Создайте файл edit.php. (измените в нужном месте на: <? echo "<a href='./edit.php?red={$items['id']}'>Редактировать</a>"?>) При переходе на него по ссылке через GET параметр передайте id редактируемой записи. Создайте форму для редактрования записи и загрузите нужную запись из БД (получите запись по ее id). А код для обновления записи в БД у вас уже есть

Comment: Отслеживание нажатия кнопки "сохранить" сделайте по аналогии с имеющимся у вас кодом: if(isset($_POST['save'])) выполняем обновление записи в БД. Ну и кнопке сохранения не забыть задать нужный name="save" .